# How to keep my date value correct for submitting to API?

Tags: angular, typescript, date, .net-core, gmt

I'm on an angular app with .net core 3.1 backend.
I use a material datepicker.
When I pick up a date I can see in the console it looks like

```
Wed Feb 10 2021 00:00:00 GMT+0100
```

However, when it arrives in my web api controller, the value has changed. It's now in utc and therefor, it's set to the previous day

```
StartDate.ToString()
//"09/02/2021 23:00:00"
StartDate.Kind
//Utc
```

I understand it's something to do with gmt vs utc.
But I'm not sure about the best way to fix it.
Any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you use `DateTime` type in your DTO models on server side.
`DateTime` does not contain any info about timezone, so I assume that json serealizer converts it into UTC if the target type cannot keep timezone info (if the target type is `DateTime`).

Please try to use `DateTimeOffset` type instead. Let me know if it helps.